# выполнение bash скрипта при старте демона

Tags: bash, daemon

ЗДравствуйте!

Есть  демон:

```
[Unit]
Description=super desc
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/root/super.pid

User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/root/super/value/ --rpcuser=admin --rpcpassword=123456 --httpdendpoint=127.0.0.1:8080 --daemon
KillSignal=15
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

И есть скрипт который курлит что-то /etc/systemd/system/curl.sh
Собственно, как и что в мой демон прописать что бы при старте или рестарте сервиса выполнялся скрипт?
Но важно что бы курлило только когда сервис запустился и реально "раздуплился"..

Comment: можно свой скрипт положить в init.d  и добавить как сервис.  и тогда внутри вашего скрипта при старте можно указать какие команды выполнить. не рассматривали ?

Comment: Решил пока сделать отдельный сервис:
 
[unit]
Description=OneTime Curl
After=some.service
Requires=some.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot

User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.curl.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target